# How to remove authentication token with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, token

I have a react native app. And a logout api call. So I try now to implement the logout api call in react. And the problem I am facing is that the token will not be removed after I called the api call logout. But I tested in swagger and that works. The token have been removed when I trigger the api call logout.

So I have a service:

```
export const logoutRequest = async () => {
    
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/logout/");

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

and a context:

```
    const onLogout = () => {
        logoutRequest();
    };
```

and the view that calls the onLogout:

```
<AuthButton icon="email" mode="contained" onPress={() => onLogout()}>
                            Logout
                        </AuthButton>
```

and to pass the token for the other api data calls. I am using this function"

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const retrieveToken = async () => {
    try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Token");

        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        
        return null;
    }
};
```

Question: how to remove authentication token in react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user logout successfully, the app should remove the `token` from async storage.

```js
export const removeToken = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem("Token");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Renove authentication token failed :", error?.message);
  }
};
```

Then

```js
export const logoutRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/logout/");
    await removeToken();
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```